# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: TimedPromise timed out after 300000 ms Stacktrace:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-play, geckodriver

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: TimedPromise timed out after 300000 ms
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:186:5
TimeoutError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:475:5
bail@chrome://remote/content/marionette/sync.js:226:19
```

```
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1,5))
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source(),'html.parser')

except TimeoutException:
    print("DNS error or Timeout")
    cache={}
    ips=resolve_with_cache(hostname)
```

I have been experiencing an issue while running a Python script to crawl data from the Google Play Store using Selenium (version 4.9.1), Geckodriver (version 0.33), and Firefox (version 113.0.2) on my EC2 instance. Initially, the code runs smoothly, but after about 5 or 6 successful executions, my EC2 instance crashes. Upon investigation, I noticed that there is a sudden increase in CPU usage just before the crash occurs.

Here are the specific steps and observations:

I am running the code on an EC2 instance.
The script is scheduled to run every 30 minutes.
Initially, the code executes successfully for several iterations.
However, after approximately 5 or 6 iterations, the EC2 instance crashes.
Upon checking the logs, I found the following error message above.
I am particularly concerned about the sudden increase in CPU usage, which seems to be correlated with the crashes. I'm unsure why this is happening and how to address it. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide insights into the possible reasons behind this issue and suggest potential solutions or optimizations.

Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance!

Comment: You need to post your code, show us your efforts, before expecting an answer.

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . What is the url of the page in question?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have made adjustments to my code, specifically regarding the "driver.get(url)" portion. I apologize for the confusion caused by my previous question.

After making these adjustments, I observed that my code runs smoothly for 5 or 6 iterations. However, I am uncertain which block of code might be causing the issues. To address this, I plan to conduct tests on each block of code individually in order to identify any potential bugs.

Once again, thank you for your assistance, and I appreciate any further guidance you can provide.